# Create one single datepicker with predefined dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-range, daterangepicker

I'm using [daterangepicker 2.1.13.](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config)

I want to create single datepicker with predefined dates as it is possible with ranges. So, if user clicks on it, it will show predefined values (like today on 8 clock and tomorrow on that clock) and a possibility to select the date and time custom.

I didnt see such an application in [examples](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples) but since it is very simple use case for daterangepicker, i believe it should be somehow possible.

Most closest thing i could do is following but the predefined's are still ranges instead of single dates

```
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "showDropdowns": true,
    "showWeekNumbers": true,
    "timePicker": true,
    "timePicker24Hour": true,
    "autoApply": true,
    "ranges": {
        "Today": [
            "2016-02-10T19:32:41.307Z",
            "2016-02-10T19:32:41.307Z"
        ],
        "Yesterday": [
            "2016-02-09T19:32:41.307Z",
            "2016-02-09T19:32:41.307Z"
        ],
        "Last 7 Days": [
            "2016-02-04T19:32:41.307Z",
            "2016-02-10T19:32:41.307Z"
        ],
        "Last 30 Days": [
            "2016-01-12T19:32:41.307Z",
            "2016-02-10T19:32:41.307Z"
        ],
        "This Month": [
            "2016-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
            "2016-02-29T22:59:59.999Z"
        ],
        "Last Month": [
            "2015-12-31T23:00:00.000Z",
            "2016-01-31T22:59:59.999Z"
        ]
    },
    "startDate": "02/04/2016",
    "endDate": "02/10/2016"
}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});
```

Comment: I have still no clear-cut answer for this but it is though worth to deal with css -to hide unwanted second calendar- and the callback functions of the framework -to deal with the end-date of the framework- to achieve like this. At least, this is what I did.